# why main function do not recognise if another function return float type number

Tags: c++

I am give 2 and -2 as input and suppose to get 0.25 as output. But the result I am getting is 1.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float power(float x, float y);

int main()
{
    float x=0, y=0;
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<power(x, y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

float power(float x, float y)
{
    float c;
    if (y == 0) return 1;
    c=x*power(x, (y+1));
    return (1/c);
}
```

If I `return c;` instead of `return 1/c;` and in the main function put `cout<<1/power(x, y);` I am getting the right result. Any one please can suggest a reason behind this it would be helpful for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you do `1/` in main, you only do it once, to the final result. When you do it in `power`, you do it on every recursive call, to every intermediate result. The two are not equivalent.

Comment: Write out your program flow on paper and you'll immediately see why.

Comment: `1` seems like a reasonable result to me...

Comment: does your recursion even stop?

Comment: That's probably because yo didn't provide the input correctly (for instance closed `stdin`), such that you actually calculate `0^0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the wrong result, is that in your recursive call, you constantly invert the result:

```
float power(float x, float y) {
    float c;
    cout << y << endl;
    if (y == 0) return 1;
    c=x*power(x, (y+1)); //result previous call (can already been inversed)
    return (1/c); //the inversion step
}
```

What thus happens is:

```
pow(2,-2)
    pow(2,-1)
        pow(2,0) = 1
        return 1/(2*1)=0.5
    return 1/(2*0.5)=1 (here you undo the effect)
```

I've omitted the calculations in between, because these are not "relevant" to show what is wrong. Or a more advanced example:

```
pow(2,-4)
    pow(2,-3)
        pow(2,-2)
            pow(2,-1)
                pow(2,0) = 1
                return 1/(2*1)=0.5
            return 1/(2*0.5)=1 (here you undo the effect)
        return 1/(2*1)=0.5
    return 1/(2*0.5)=1 (here you undo the effect)
```

Thus you multiply by `x` and divide by `x`. If the original `y` is even, it will always result in `1.00`, otherwise it will result in `1/x`. Furthermore this method will never end if you provide a positive exponent.

If you don't invert constantly, it will (in the case of a negative `y`), simply calculate `x^-y`, so you can do the inversion post-call.

But your method is in general rather error-prone: performing increment/decrement on floats as well as checking on zero is known to ask for trouble. Furthermore your algorithm isn't very efficient. A better way to solve this (with integral power), is:

```
float power(float x, int y) {
    if(y < 0) {
        return 1.0f/power_positive(x,-y);
    } else {
        return power_positive(x,y);
    }
}
float power_positive(float x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) {
        return 1.0f;
    }
    float r = power_positive(x*x,y>>0x01);
    if(y&0x01) {
        r *= x;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This algorithm will work faster as well since it divides the exponent by half each time. As said before, it however works only for integral exponents. You can generalize it. But I would trust the 80x87-coprocessor more with floating point arithmetic anyway.